# Javascript or jQuery. Launch multiple URLs pulled from input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, window.open

I wrote a basic function as follows:

```
        function launchIt() {
            var input = document.getElementById('webaddy'),
                webAddy = input.value;
            if (webAddy) {
                    // initialize array
                    var arr = new Array(6);
                    arr[0] = "/css/img/bg-home.jpg?reset=1";
                    arr[1] = "/css/img/bg-large.jpg?reset=1";
                    arr[2] = "/css/img/bg-medium.jpg?reset=1";
                    arr[3] = "/css/img/bg-small.jpg?reset=1";
                    arr[4] = "/css/img/bg-xlarge.jpg?reset=1";
                    arr[5] = "/css/img/bg-xsmall.jpg?reset=1";

                    // display all values
                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        alert(webAddy + arr[i]);
                    };
            }
        }
```

It works. I get the web address from the webaddy input field's value. I want to change the `alert()` to something like `window.open`. I have tried `window.open`, but it only opens the first array item and then stops. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to open 6 windows at once?

Comment: @user1729506 can u create a fiddle with ur code

Comment: Take a look at the popup blocker

Comment: @Jack Yes. One after the other, but basically...yes. It's just 6. If it were more, like 60-600, I'd look for a different solution. But it'll never be more than six. Not in this case.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar I had earlier, but it didn't work. It works when I run the html file locally on any browser, though.

Comment: @user1105047 That was the problem! I forgot to account for native blockers. Since I had never installed an extension, I foolishly assumed it wasn't an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was my browser's built-in popup block! Thanks to @user1105047!